# How can I specify a team to sign in with Slack

Tags: omniauth, slack-api, slack

I'm building a website and I added "Sign in with Slack" button.
I'm using omniauth-slack (latest 8b2371) and it works well.
But I want to allow only the users from my own Slack team.

There is `team` parameter, but the behavior is not so good (https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth).
It automatically choose the team only if a user is signed in to the team.
Otherwise, the user have to type their team domain manually.
And it gets worse if the user is signed in to another team; it attempts to sign in with the other team although my team id is specified (even, one cannot change/choose the team domain to sign in, there is Authorize button only).

I can disallow the users from other team by checking their team id in the callback action, but I don't want to confuse my team members when they sign in my website with Slack.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  It is 2 years later and I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the workspace's subdomain instead of the Slack default in the authorization URL. In python-social-auth docs this was as simple as defining a new backend, e.g.:

```
class MyTeamSlackOAuth2(SlackOAuth2):
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://myteamhere.slack.com/oauth/authorize'
```

And using it instead of the stock one. I don't know what the parallel action would be in omniauth but I will leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)